# Ubuntu terminal lagging one input behind

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Today I started to notice something really annoying, when I type something in my terminal
the input laggs behind, I will show an example because this is really odd

For example when i type this

```
sudo apt update
```

I see

```
sudo apt updat
```

Only when I now type another character or hit a key the terminal updates to show

```
sudo apt update
```

But since I typed something the Terminal is behind again.

The only thing that I changed on my system that could cause this was an update today

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Currently I sit on Pop!_OS 21.10 and my Terminal is Alacritty, but the terminal doesnt matter, I got the same problem with other Terminals

Comment: What is your shell? Does the problem occur in other shells? Does the problem occur after `PS1='$ '`? Does the problem occur after you invoke `cat` and type anything?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes this happens with all shells (I'm using zsh with omz), I think I can force this to happen by using tab to autocomplete something.
Typing PS1='$ ' does nothing